# Improving my R function performance with VCM

Tags: r, performance, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am running a simulation using Varying-Coefficient Models, yet there are some adjustments. There is no R package that can do what I am looking for.
My code is not running fast enough. I am looking forward to making `vcm` function run faster

```
###########################################################################
###########################################################################
###                                                                     ###
###                        EPANECHNIKOV FUNCTION                        ###
###                                                                     ###
###########################################################################
###########################################################################

epan <- function(t,h){

  idx    = 0.75 * (1 - (t/h)**2) / h
  kernal = 0.50 * (abs(idx) + idx)
  kernal
}

###########################################################################
###########################################################################
###                                                                     ###
###                             UNPENALIZED                             ###
###                      VARYING COEFFICIENT MODEL                      ###
###                                                                     ###
###########################################################################
###########################################################################


vcm <- function(x,y,z,z0) {
  n = dim(x)[1]
  p = dim(x)[2]
  
  n0 = length(z0)
  
  Z = outer(z,z0,"-")
  Width = sd(z) * n**(-0.2) * 2
  H = sapply(X = 1:n0, FUN = function(X) epan(t = Z[,X], h = Width))
  diag(H) = 0
  W_h = H / rep(colSums(H), each = n0)
  
  G = lapply(X = 1:n0, FUN = function(X) cbind(x, Z[,X]*x))
  
  AB = matrix(NA, n0, 2*p)
  II = 1e-4 * diag(2*p)  # to avoid singularity
  for(i in 1:n0) {
    AB[i,] = solve(crossprod(G[[i]] * W_h[,i], G[[i]]) + II) %*% crossprod(G[[i]] * W_h[,i], y)
  }
  
  AB
}
```

What I have done so far is

- Profile the code and see where the slow part
- Used `sapply` and `lapply` instead of `for` loop, yet no significant difference

How to use the code? Here is a small simulation where the code functions are used.

```
n = 100000
p = 5
n0 = 1000

z = runif(n)
z0 = seq(0.05, 0.95, length.out = n0)

x = MASS::mvrnorm(n, rep(0,p), diag(p))

gz = cbind(2*sin(2*pi*z), 3*z*(1-2*z), exp(-2*z + z**2), 2*z, 0)

y = apply(x * gz, 1, sum) + rnorm(n)

vvc_m = vcm(x,y,z,z0)
```

I am willing to use Rcpp or any other libraries if they would significantly improve my code's performance even though I have no experience with Rcpp.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: What did your profiling tell you? Where are the bottlenecks?

Comment: @jblood94 lapply and sapply

Comment: And even more so, the `solve` inside a `for` loop inverting a large matrix.

Comment: @jblood94 ‘solve’ inverts a (2p x 2p) matrix and it’s usually a small matrix

Answer (score 2):

The `apply` and `lapply` are not needed. Also, `G[[i]] * W_h[,i]` needs to be computed only once. These changes will shave off a few seconds, but the bulk of the time is spent in the `for` loop. You are probably correct that any gains there will have to be with `Rcpp`/`RcppArmadillo`.

```
vcm2 <- function(x,y,z,z0) {
  n = dim(x)[1]
  p = dim(x)[2]
  
  n0 = length(z0)
  
  Z = outer(z,z0,"-")
  Width = sd(z) * n**(-0.2) * 2
  H = epan(Z, Width)
  diag(H) = 0
  W_h = H / rep(colSums(H), each = n0)
  
  AB = matrix(NA, n0, 2*p)
  II = 1e-4 * diag(2*p)  # to avoid singularity
  G = matrix(x, n, 2*p)
  idx = (p + 1):(2*p)
  for(i in 1:n0) {
    G[,idx] = Z[,i]*x
    GW_h = G*W_h[,i]
    AB[i,] = solve(crossprod(GW_h, G) + II) %*% crossprod(GW_h, y)
  }
  
  AB
}

system.time(vvc_m <- vcm(x,y,z,z0))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   21.71    5.42   27.14
system.time(vvc_m2 <- vcm2(x,y,z,z0))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   19.45    3.52   22.99
identical(vvc_m, vvc_m2)
#> [1] TRUE
```